# Anatomy of a Typical Java Web Application

Tags: web

I am attending a training course where they presented the following graphic as the **Anatomy of a Typical Java Web Application**.  Is it too sweeping of a statement, or is it largely accurate?

Here it goes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: My experience is drawn mostly from non-Java platforms, though I have some limited experience with Java - but [mostly](http://bash.org/?946461) [I'm](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2807908) [not](http://bash.org/?338364) [a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fr6E.png) [fan](https://shitcode.net/worst/language/java))

It's accurate - but only for applications using that architecture - which makes this statement somewhat of a tautology.

I'll break it down:

- Service Consumer Perspective

  - A "service consumer" is also more commonly known as a *client*.
  - "Service interface files" are *not* needed to build a client.
  - I assume by "interface files" it's referring to things like a SOAP WSDL document or Swagger file for REST services. These files are not generally used by clients at runtime but are used to automatically create client class-libraries at design-time - but you can always build a client without any code-generation or reuse of Java `interface` types.
  - If it is referring to the reuse of the server/application's Java `interface` types then the diagram is only accurate for client+server applications that are all-Java and are both designed/created at the same time (which is an old practice from the days of SOAP). Thesedays everything made in the past 5-10 years is RESTful and returns JSON data, but Java `interface` types are insufficient to model unstructured data like JSON ([given you can't model discriminated-unions without concrete classes... in exception handlers, egods](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/02/16/an-ingenious-workaround-to-emulate-sum-types-in-java/), and discriminated-unions are an important tool to model JSON in OOP languages).
- Service Provider Perspective

  - I disagree with the use of the term "Front controller" being used to refer to what is commonly known as a *back-end* web-service controller, Servlet, or Spring Controller as "front-end" generally refers to the user-facing UI/UX, such as the rendered HTML+JS, an SPA front-end, or rich-client/fat-client (granted, this would be the "service consumer").
  - You don't need "service metadata" to have a web-application or a web-service - though if you're shipping a web-service designed to be consumed by disparate or non-first-party clients then its a good idea to make a WSDL, Swagger, or whatever metadata or service-description system your platform uses so that your consumers can generate their own strongly-typed clients.
- "Service implementer perspective"

  - So this is my biggest objection: this diagram assumes that the web-service will be 3-tier and the controller/Servlet code is only a thin layer in front of "application" types located elsewhere in the system. While this is common in large-scale and complicated applications where you'll have *host-agnostic* application code that is designed to be able to run in, for example, an integration-test or unit-test host - or as a desktop application, in my experience I estimate most projects lump all application logic inside the host-specific (i.e. Spring, Servlets, etc) code because it simplifies things greatly (and because those hosts often support testability anyway - and the idea of reusing application code libraries *as-is* for desktop or mobile applications just doesn't work out well in reality given the massive differences between the disconnected and stateless model of web-service requests compared to the needs of stateful in-process client applications).

In summary: it's not *wrong*, but I don't believe it accurately describes the majority of (Java) web-applications I've personally dealt with... but this is my subjective opinion and I know that Java web-application and web-service frameworks like Spring and Java EE are designed for and encourage 3-tier architecture, I wouldn't describe them doing-so as an example of the [pit-of-success](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/) - I feel this is partly due to shortcomings in the Java language design (and the fact these frameworks were designed over 20 years ago before things like generics were added to the language).